# How do I make TFS automatically delete older versions of files?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I have a Team Foundation Server which has limited disk space available.  In order to maintain it I need to delete older versions of the files that it stores.

Ideally, I would only want it to delete the version if:

1. It is older than particular date, and
2. It has a minimum of 15 versions

How do I do this?

Comment: HDD's are safer to upgrade than deleting old versions of files out of the TFS database.

Comment: What is HDD? Can you please give me some more information?

Comment: HDD's are hard drive disks. I think Dave is right here. It would be a terribly bad idea to start removing older revisions from tfs for existing source controlled items.

Comment: Don't know why there are downvotes. It is a perfectly valid question and a great opportunity for the OP to learn about TFS under the hood as jessehouwing's answer explains.

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard way to do this, and there's a reason for this. TFS usually tries to store just the base file and the differences on top of that, so if you start removing older revisions, you won't be gaining much. At most the size of the diff of these two versions.

Upgrading the disk space of your TFS Server is definitely the long term solution here.

If you must reduce the size of your projects, consider destroying old branches that have no use anymore. [You can destroy whole files and folders which will remove them and the history associated to them from TFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386005.aspx). By default you can only access this feature through the commandline and you need to have permission to destroy items in TFS. [There is an extension for the Source Control Explorer that adds the Destroy command to the context menu in Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c6642e7f-1a58-4ff0-aef9-0322dcc2b28d).

If you're running automated tests from a Team Build server, then test attachments may also be a reason for your TFS server growing out of its allotted space. [Microsoft released a command line utility to clean up the Test Attachments](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3d37ce86-05f1-4165-957c-26aaa5ea1010).

If you truly want to reset the version history you could branch your code to a clean Team Project and then decommission the old one.

Answer (score 2):

You should also be sure of which component of TFS is using the most disk space.

You can run the following SQL query on your `Tfs_Collection` database to see which tables are consuming the most space.

```
-- Table rows and data sizes 
CREATE TABLE #t (     [name] NVARCHAR(128),    [rows] CHAR(11),    reserved VARCHAR(18),     data VARCHAR(18),     index_size VARCHAR(18),    unused VARCHAR(18)) 
GO

INSERT #t 
EXEC [sys].[sp_MSforeachtable] 'EXEC sp_spaceused ''?''' 
GO

SELECT 
    name as TableName, 
    Rows, 
    ROUND(CAST(REPLACE(reserved, ' KB', '') as float) / 1024,2) as ReservedMB, 
    ROUND(CAST(REPLACE(data, ' KB', '') as float) / 1024,2) as DataMB, 
    ROUND(CAST(REPLACE(index_size, ' KB', '') as float) / 1024,2) as IndexMB, 
    ROUND(CAST(REPLACE(unused, ' KB', '') as float) / 1024,2) as UnusedMB 
FROM #t 
ORDER BY CAST(REPLACE(reserved, ' KB', '') as float) DESC 
GO

DROP TABLE #t 
GO
```

If you are using Microsoft Test Manager, it's possible that Test Attachments are using more space than you thought. Take a look at this blog post for more information on how to interpret this query and what to do: [TFS2010: Test Attachment Cleaner and why you should be using it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2011/02/12/tfs2010-test-attachment-cleaner-and-why-you-should-be-using-it.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot Grant! I will run this script and get back to you. I'm taking a week break, I will return with queries later on. Thanks :)